# SQL Find Groups that do not have Value

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find some data grouped by ids like so

```
Create Table FormFields (Label varchar(100), FormId int)
Insert Into FormFields Values ('First Name', 1)
Insert Into FormFields Values ('Last Name', 1)
Insert Into FormFields Values ('Email', 1)

Insert Into FormFields Values ('First Name', 2)
Insert Into FormFields Values ('Last Name', 2)
Insert Into FormFields Values ('Email', 2)
Insert Into FormFields Values ('Phone', 2)

Insert Into FormFields Values ('Email', 3)
Insert Into FormFields Values ('Phone', 3)
Insert Into FormFields Values ('Birthday', 3)
```

But I'm trying to find all instances where the "group" (the data with the same id) does not have an entry for "First Name" and "Last Name"

I've tried:

```
select distinct Label, FormId 
from FormFields
where Label not in
(
    select distinct Label
    from FormFields
    where Label= 'First Name' or Label= 'Last Name'
)
order by FormId
```

But that only gives the other fields without a reference to see if there is actually a first and last name.

My Desired output would just show Formfields where ID = 3 since that group (of items listed with id 3) do not have an entry for "First Name" and "Last Name"

Thanks for the help here, very confused if this is even possible.

Comment: Instead of html can you post a create table statement and some insert statements? Also, not really sure what you want for output here.

Comment: @SeanLange edited my post. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes....yes it does.

Comment: @Charkins12 I've updated what you've tried and posted an answer. Give it a try and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing data and a clearer explanation. There are several ways to accomplish this. Here is one of them.

```
select *
from FormFields
where FormId
not in
(
    select FormId
    from FormFields
    where Label in ('First Name', 'Last Name')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have tries is very close to your solution. Try change what you've tried like below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Label, FormId 
FROM FormFields
WHERE FormId NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT FormId
    FROM FormFields
    WHERE Label= 'First Name' OR Label= 'Last Name'
)
ORDER By FormId
```

OR another solution :

```
SELECT * FROM FormFields 
WHERE FormId NOT IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT FormId 
    FROM FormFields 
    WHERE Label IN ('First Name' , 'Last Name')
)
```

Comment: Great work, had to give the answer to Sean because he was first and I used his answer yesterday.